# Access field of type after Json decode in elm

Tags: json, elm

I'm trying to do some small steps with elm width decoding a json to an type. My type is e.g.:

```
    type alias Project = 
        { title : String
        , description : String
        }
```

and my function with the decode logic and display the title of a project.

```
    render : (String, String) -> Html Msg
    render (jsonString, otherString) =
        let project = Decode.decodeString projectDecoder (jsonString)
        in div [] [ text (project.title) ]
```

```
projectDecoder : Decode.Decoder Project
projectDecoder =
    Decode.map2
        Project
        (Decode.at [ "title" ] Decode.string)
        (Decode.at [ "description" ] Decode.string)
```

But I've got a error which indicate that the decoder will return a Error instead a project.

> This is not a record, so it has no fields to access!
>
> 32|     in div [] [ text (project.title) ]
>                             This `project` value is a:
>
> ```
> Result Decode.Error Project
> ```
>
> But I need a record with a title field!

Answer (score 3):

Reading the elm guide carefully will help to solve this problem: https://guide.elm-lang.org/error_handling/result.html

We need to handle both cases of `Ok` and `Err` with a `case`.

```
render : (String, String) -> Html Msg
render (jsonString, otherString) =
    let project = Decode.decodeString projectDecoder (jsonString)
    in 
        case project of
            Ok status -> div [] [ text (status.title) ]
            Err _ -> div [] [ text ("A error occurs") ]
```